# Measuring unique numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, unique

OK guys I solved it! My code was correct the system was stupid and needed an endl after the output... Thanks to all of you for replying!

Can you find any bugs in my code?? I'm trying to measure the number of unique integers in an array. I use this code but it there seems to be a bug somewhere.
EXAMPLE:

Input:4,1,15,10,1

Output:3

It is correct my code outputs 3 as well, tested it with larger input and again it was correct but when I send my code to my university system for evaluation it compiles the code correctly but tells me my output is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{   

    int n,d;
    cin>>n;
    int *A=new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>A[i];

    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        d=i;
        while(d>0 && A[d] < A[d-1])
        {   
            swap(A[d],A[d-1]);
            d--;
        }
    }

    int count=1;
    int tmp=A[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(tmp!=A[i]){count+=1;tmp=A[i];}
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell us what is the issue that you are having so that we can help you. Also try debugging your code, it will help you find the root of the problem.

Comment: It is a college exercise we are to find the unique numbers in an array and output that number with cout. But when I send my code the system sais it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, read your input/output wrong. Are you able to get the result from your university system to see what it returns?

Comment: Unfortunately not right now, if I find something I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with your sorting algorithm. This will work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = a;
}

int main()
{   

    int n,d;
    cin>>n;
    int *A=new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>A[i];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j < n; j++) {
        if (A[j] < A[i])
            swap(A[i], A[j]);
    }
    }

    int count=1;
    int tmp=A[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(tmp!=A[i]){count+=1;tmp=A[i];}
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I don't get the error in my sorting I used Insertion sort and don't see an error there.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your program, did a few runs and did not notice anything unusual. Also, your bubble sort algorithm, though not very efficient, is still faster than Venkatesh' suggestion, which is bound to run in O(n^2) time.

Also, try to be more accurate in describing your problem. Just telling us it has a bug, is not very helpfull.
Note that you can do:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin>>A[i];
    d=i;
    while(d>0 && A[d] < A[d-1])
    {   
        swap(A[d],A[d-1]);
        d--;
    }
}
```

saving you a loop.

Comment: Thanks for testing, I don't find errors either. Isn't my sorting method Insertion sort??

Comment: You are right, the first time i saw an insertion sort, it was introduced to me as bubble sort. I still mix them up.

Comment: Thanks for the loop optimization, there is a little error though in it but your logic is good. Notice that i starts from 1 not 0.

Comment: You are right again, sorry, it is late at night here, and I am not as sharp as ever...The first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will not run, because d == 0

Comment: Don't worry I do weirder things during daytime with my code ;)